# MongoDB: How to get main document and all ancestors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I need to create a publication, which gives me a set of documents from the collection. Here you can see, how the documents are related to each other:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "peRuJcPMDzZgTvWSX", 
    "author" : "author", 
    "type" : "article", 
    "parent" : "mnfTFfZ7Fqcu6ZJ7T", 
    "ancestors" : [ "hbSycmNNvmdqvpchX", "mnfTFfZ7Fqcu6ZJ7T" ] 
}
{ 
    "_id" : "mnfTFfZ7Fqcu6ZJ7T", 
    "article" : "article", 
    "parent" : "hbSycmNNvmdqvpchX", 
    "ancestors" : [ "hbSycmNNvmdqvpchX" ] 
}
{ 
    "_id" : "hbSycmNNvmdqvpchX", 
    "title" : "title", 
    "ancestors" : [ ] 
}
```

So what I know is the ID of the first document and I need also all ancestors in the publication.

```
Meteor.publish('list', function(id) {
    check(id, String);
    return Collection.find({}); // WRONG: gives me ALL documents
    return Collection.find({ _id: id }) // WRONG: gives me only the first document (main)
    // NEEDED: Main document and all ancestors
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to pull the main document with `{_id:id}` and subsequentially pull the ancestors from that property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a `.findOne()` first then return an array of cursors:

```
Meteor.publish('list', function(id) {
  check(id, String);
  const ancestors = Collection.findOne(id).ancestors;
  if ( ancestors ){
    return [ Collection.find(id), Collection.find({_id: {$in: ancestors}})];
  } else {
    return Collection.find(id);
  }
});
```

You could also do this with a single `.find()` using an `$or` but that would likely be slower.

Comment: There is a missing `)` in `...ancestors}}]`. And shouldn't it be a comma in the array, instead of an semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

You could this [publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) to publish a *join* relationship in Meteor:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('list', function(id) {
  // checking here ...

  return {
    find() {
      return Collection.find(id);
    },
    children: [{
      find(doc) {
        return Collection.find({
          _id: {
            $in: doc.ancestors
          }
        });
      },
    }],
  };
});
```

This package makes sure that your publish is reactive, e.g. if the value of `ancestors` changes the data published to client should be updated to reflect that change. If you just use `findOne` in publication to get the `ancestors` list, then the data sent to client will not be updated when the value of `ancestors` change